# Problem with is_user_logged_in() function in some pages

Tags: login, logout

I faced a problem with this function is_user_logged_in() in the header to test if the user is logged in to some code.
Its working just in some pages like homepage but the other sub-pages not I don't know why!!!

Comment: In what file you're calling the is_user_logged_in() function?

Comment: In the header.php of the template

Comment: No answer till now

Comment: describe your problem more. and can you use the developer tools to make sure that your header file is included in those other pages?

Comment: like, do you have custom templates?